# Does the new "privacy" button have a log?

Tags: zeitgeist, logging, privacy

I was just wondering if there was a log that shows exactly what the various applications are taking a history of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The is no "log" in the sense of a human readable text file, as this information is stored by Zeitgeist. What you can do however, is install Gnome-Activity-Journal, which will give you a read out of everything it has stored in the database.

[image: Gnome-Activity-Journal]